# Google Script - getActiveUser() Email/UserName (Not working for diff domains)

Tags: email, dns, google-apps-script, google-sheets

We could not take the Email ID from different domain users using:
Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() in Google Script.
Is there any alternative ways?
If anyone know, please share, it will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible and its docummented.
This is done for privacyy reasons and to avoid people collecting emails.
Your only alternative is to publish a webapp that runs as the user (not owner). In that case it works (because it alerts the user)